# Duration measurement precision on STM32H7

Tags: arm, stm32

According to STM32H753 datasheet the precision of the PLL-generated clock is 0.7% (for a VCO of 800MHz which is my case).

[image]

Which means the precision of the general purpose timers is also 0.7% since they are clocked by the same source ?

I would have liked to measure more precisely the accuracy of an external signal. Is there a way to do so ?

I know there is a so-called High Resolution Timer but it seems it is more used to provide output signal (rather than measuring internal events) ?

Comment: If it is locked to the crystal input then the error on the crystal (eg; 50ppm) is what determines your accuracy.  Jitter usually means the absolute error in the location of the edges (given in +/- ps here).  You can divide this error by the amount of time you average over to get your relative jitter error, and add that to the relative error of the crystal.  I'm not sure what they mean by "long-term jitter", perhaps you should ask on electronics.stackexchange.com what that means.

Comment: @TomV the imprecision I've seen in the real product (différence between the external signal that is supposed to be very very accurate and the timing measured by STM32) is very close to the "long term jitter" mentioned in the datasheet. There is no definition of long term jitter

Comment: The measure versus the 'typical' datasheet maybe a coincidence.  I would agree that the crystal spec is one aspect.  If the PLL is up/down converting and by what amounts will also contribute to the accuracy.  The (typical) jitter is clock to clock and for longer periods, it will average to something else.

Comment: jitter != clock acuracy.

Comment: @Misaz could you elaborate ?

Comment: @artlessnoise what do you mean by "The (typical) jitter is clock to clock and for longer periods" Do you mean source clock to PLL output clock ? This is how I understood "long term jitter". The PLL introduces an imprecision of around 0.7% in average

Comment: The jitter may averaged out.  So, if you have .7% jitter, it does not mean a derived clock is .7% accurate.  If a derived clock is 1000 periods, then the average is some stddev of the jitter for the individual clocks.  I think the PLL will have some addition 'error' as it take the crystal PPM and upscales it.  Misaz is correct, you want clock accuracy of the derived timer.  Notice the spec... typical and +/-,